# Align main content vertically center of screen when header is available

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to align main content vertically center of screen. I did vertically center of div. But I was not able to do center of screen due to header. I want to do main content vertically center of screen when header is there. Any help would be appreciated.

I have built it at [codeopen.io](https://codepen.io/dharmesh_parekh/pen/rNxzGqo) so you guys can play with it.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #13385f;
  height: 100%;
}

.nav-menu a {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-menu a.active {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-menu a:hover {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.0.0-alpha1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<header>
  <div class="p-3 px-md-4">
    <div class="d-flex flex-column flex-md-row align-items-center container justify-content-between">
      <div class="my-0 ml-md-4 mr-md-auto">
        <h5 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">
          <!-- <img src="assets/images/logo.png" class="img-reponsive" width="50" /> -->
          <b class="text-white">LOGO</b>
        </h5>
      </div>
      <nav class="my-2 my-md-0 mr-md-4 nav-menu">
        <a class="p-2 active" href="#">Sign in</a>
        <a class="p-2" href="#">Register</a>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>

<main role="main" class="h-100">
  <div class="container d-flex h-100 align-items-center justify-content-center">
    <div class="row text-white">
      I'm vertically centered
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<header>
  <div class="p-3 px-md-4">
    <div class="d-flex flex-column flex-md-row align-items-center container justify-content-between fixed-header">
      <div class="my-0 ml-md-4 mr-md-auto">
        <h5 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">
          <!-- <img src="assets/images/logo.png" class="img-reponsive" width="50" /> -->
          <b class="text-white">LOGO</b>
        </h5>
      </div>
      <nav class="my-2 my-md-0 mr-md-4 nav-menu">
        <a class="p-2 active" href="#">Sign in</a>
        <a class="p-2" href="#">Register</a>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

I think you want your header to be fixed on top if that is your problem add **fixed-top** class to the second div of your header to make your header fixed top. check the second div in the above code.